# Problems running npm with node to increase memory

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I have an Ubuntu docker container that has npm installed using nvm. In order to compile my code I am trying to run:

```
   node --max_old_space_size=4096 npm run build
```

But I get:

```
  root@faf3418e77d0:/myproject# node --max_old_space_size=4096 npm run build
  module.js:538
  throw err;
  ^

 Error: Cannot find module '/myproject/npm'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
     at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
   root@faf3418e77d0:/myproject#
```

I have npm so I do not understand how this is happening. I can run npm from any folder at my docker container. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using the command:  which npm
I found where it is located and used that complete info in my script.
Thx